# How to install Python 3.6.6 on Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

How to install Python 3.6.6 on Mac? Can anyone tell me the Commit Identifier for Python 3.6.6? I can't find the link to download

Comment: Is 3.6.5 no good for you ? (That seems to be the version on current macOS High Sierra).

Answer (score 2):

You can find the latest release here -> https://www.python.org/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Python version 3.6.5 and install it using Anaconda. Go to [this site](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos) and download Python 3.6. This will load python and many of the packages you may need to use to program in python. You also get the anaconda-navigator which is a nice package manager. Anaconda also makes it simple to use virtual environments. The anaconda documentation will walk you thru that as well as how to use the conda command. It's very good package for those who are new to python on a Mac.